# Keycloak 18 with Quarkus SSL configuration failed to use PKCS12 as keystore(*.p12)

Tags: ssl, oauth-2.0, keycloak, quarkus, pkcs#12

With jboss distribution I was able to configure keystore for SSL in standalone.xml as below and it is working fine

```xml
<tls>
    <key-stores>
        <key-store name="applicationKS">
            <credential-reference clear-text="Xxxxxx!"/>
            <implementation type="PKCS12"/>
            <file path="my-keystore.p12" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </key-store>
    </key-stores>
    <key-managers>
        <key-manager name="applicationKM" key-store="applicationKS" alias-filter="my-keystore">
            <credential-reference clear-text="Xxxxxx!"/>
        </key-manager>
    </key-managers>
    <server-ssl-contexts>
        <server-ssl-context name="applicationSSC" key-manager="applicationKM" />
    </server-ssl-contexts>
</tls>
```

But when using Quarkus distribution as per the documentation as below,

```
bin/kc.bat start --https-port=8180 --http-host=xxx.xxx.xx.xx --hostname=mymachine --https-key-store-file=my-keystore.p12 --https-key-store-password=Xxxxxx! --https-key-store-type=PKCS12 --https-protocols=TLSv1.3
```

I am getting the error as

```java
2022-06-13 16:52:58,717 ERROR [io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.rejectedExecution] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:923)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:350)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:343)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:825)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:815)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.safeExecute(DefaultPromise.java:841)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenerWithStackOverFlowProtection(DefaultPromise.java:529)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener(DefaultPromise.java:477)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.CompleteFuture.addListener(CompleteFuture.java:48)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.TCPServerBase.bind(TCPServerBase.java:103)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.listen(HttpServerImpl.java:217)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.listen(HttpServerImpl.java:149)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.listen(HttpServerImpl.java:154)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$WebDeploymentVerticle.setupTcpHttpServer(VertxHttpRecorder.java:1075)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$WebDeploymentVerticle.start(VertxHttpRecorder.java:1029)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$5(DeploymentManager.java:196)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:63)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2022-06-13 16:52:58,720 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
2022-06-13 16:52:58,720 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Unable to start HTTP server
2022-06-13 16:52:58,721 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: io.vertx.core.VertxException: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
2022-06-13 16:52:58,721 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
2022-06-13 16:52:58,721 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: keystore password was incorrect
2022-06-13 16:52:58,722 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
```

I couldn't see an argument to pass the alias name for my key(was able to given in standalone.xml as `alias-filter`). So someone please suggest where I am doing wrong in this configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Issue was with **exclamation mark(!)** in password which needs to be escaped in command like **^^!**

```
--https-key-store-password="Xxxxxx^^!"
```